# Joi validation when update (patch) in Foxx

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I use arangodb 3.0.2 and have problem with joi validation when update/patch schema.

I have user schema like this

```
_key: joi.string(),
name: joi.string().required(),
username: joi.string(),
email: joi.string().required(),
profilePicture: joi.string(),
provider: joi.object().keys({
  name: joi.string(),
  id: joi.string()
}),
interest: joi.array().items(joi.string()),
level: joi.number().default(0)
```

When I create new new user, and try to add unknown field, like status
it will throw error,

But If I update user, and add unknown field, it doesn't throw any error. Because it not validate request schema.

How to validate schema when update/patch user, with ignoring field that already exists in collection?

---

Update for routes:

```
router.post(function (req, res) {
  const user = req.body;
  let provider = user.provider.name;
  let id = user.provider.id;
  let meta;
  try {
    meta = users.save(user);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.isArangoError && e.errorNum === ARANGO_DUPLICATE) {
      throw httpError(HTTP_CONFLICT, e.message);
    }
    throw e;
  }
  Object.assign(user, meta);
  res.status(201);
  res.set('location', req.makeAbsolute(
    req.reverse('detail', {key: user._key})
  ));
  res.send(user);
}, 'create')
.body(User, 'The user to create.')
.response(201, User, 'The created user.')
.error(HTTP_CONFLICT, 'The user already exists.')
.summary('Create a new user')
.description(dd`
  Creates a new user from the request body and
  returns the saved document.
`);

router.patch(':key', function (req, res) {
  const key = req.pathParams.key;
  const patchData = req.body;
  let user;
  try {
    users.update(key, patchData);
    user = users.document(key);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.isArangoError && e.errorNum === ARANGO_NOT_FOUND) {
      throw httpError(HTTP_NOT_FOUND, e.message);
    }
    if (e.isArangoError && e.errorNum === ARANGO_CONFLICT) {
      throw httpError(HTTP_CONFLICT, e.message);
    }
    throw e;
  }
  res.send(user);
}, 'update')
.pathParam('key', keySchema)
.body(joi.object().description('The data to update the user with.'))
.response(User, 'The updated user.')
.summary('Update a user')
.description(dd`
  Patches a user with the request body and
  returns the updated document.
`);
```

This is my routes, as you can see. When I post new user, it will validate user schema, so if I add unknown field, it will give me some error.

But I patch user, it will not validate user schema, because on "body" I'm not set as User Schema. But if add User Schema there, it will check required field, so I can't just patch some know field.

Comment: Hi @de_3, can you provide an example of the routes where you are using the schema? I'm not entirely sure what's going on.

Comment: Hi @AlanPlum, I've update my question, I've add user routes there. is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure a certain schema for both, creation (`.post()` route) and update (`.patch()` route), make sure to define the schema only once and reference it in both routes instead of writing it twice inline in `.body()` ([DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

```
let userSchema = joi.object().keys({
  _key: joi.string(),
  name: joi.string().required(),
  username: joi.string(),
  email: joi.string().required(),
  profilePicture: joi.string(),
  provider: joi.object().keys({
    name: joi.string(),
    id: joi.string()
  }),
  interest: joi.array().items(joi.string()),
  level: joi.number().default(0)
});

router.post(...)
  .body(userSchema)

router.patch(...)
  .body(userSchema)
```

It looks like you actually defined a schema like this, stored in a variable `User` and used in the POST route:

```
.body(User, 'The user to create.')
```

But you don't use the schema in the PATCH route:

```
.body(joi.object().description('The data to update the user with.'))
```

It only ensures that `req.body` is an object, but does not enforce any schema.